# How to recover from an error in a nested celery chain?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

The kind of workflow that I want to run looks like this:

```
workflow = (
    generator.s() |
    spread.s() |
    gather.s()
)
```

where `spread` is a task that replaces itself with a group.

```
from celery import Celery, group

celery_app = Celery()


@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def spread(self, numbers):
    return self.replace(group(
        (task_1.si(n) | task_2.s() | task_3.s()) for n in numbers
        )
    )
```

The whole workflow works fine and as expected.

My question is essentially only about the chains in the group created by `spread`. I don't care too much if some of them fail. I'm fine if an error somewhere in the chain would lead to a shorter list of results being passed to `gather`. However, I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I can, of course, catch exceptions in each of `task_1`, `task_2`, and `task_3` and pass on an empty dummy result. For convenience I'd really like to be able to say that on an error anywhere in the chain, please log the traceback and remove the result from the group or pass on an empty dummy result.

I've searched the documentation and GitHub issues far and wide but could not find anything. I know that I can pass an `on_error` callback to the chain but I don't know how to pass on an empty result from there (if that's even possible).

Setup:

- Python 3.6
- celery 4.2.1
- Redis broker and backend (though it's not a problem for me to switch if that would enable the behavior)